# Galaxy S4 poor Video playback Quality

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have a problem regarding S4 Video playback. I got it a few days ago. The problem is whenever I play videos from either the phone memory or from the internet the areas in the video with black or any dark color gets pixelated. 
I have tried GPU options in developer mood and I am using MX player with s/w decoding. Despite that the display of the phone is perfectly fine, in wallpapers and in games but it only happens with videos. Currently I am running Kitkat 4.4 do you think that lollipop update will fix it? and either it is a hardware or a software problem? the pic is attached to show you people problem clearly.[image: The screen shot of the problem]

Comment: Galaxy s4 has resolution of 1920 x 1080 , and you might be playing a video of lower resolution this effects the overall quality of video.

Comment: What happens when you try playing it with H/W decoding? Is this problem only for .avi files? .mp4? .mov?